# Which doge represents what number?

Tags: doge2048

From the original [2048](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) it was rather easy to tell which numbers I'm combining - after all, it says so right on the tile.

But now with [doge2048](http://doge2048.com) there is *such doge*. What doge is 16? What is 32? Is this doge secretly 2048 and the game actually keeps going beyond that?

very confuse

wow

[image: much doge, very number, wow]

Comment: what in the name of god

Comment: If this thing get posted in the Hot Question list, I will delete @FEichinger account.

Comment: @Braiam [That didn't take long](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ehGOk.png)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The doges are as follows:

## 2

[image]

## 4

[image]

## 8

[image]

## 16

[image]

## 32

[image]

## 64

[image]

## 128

[image]

## 256

[image]

## 512

[image]

## 1024

[image]

## 2048

[image]

Comment: *MY EYES! MAKE IT STOP!*

Comment: @SaintWacko If you really want a head-trip, [view revision #2 of the edit history...](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/160558/revisions)

Comment: wow so shibe very inu very pictures

Comment: This is pretty much the worst thing anyone has ever earned rep for.

Comment: Outdated; doge 2 e.g. now blinks.

Answer (score 46):

In Firefox and Internet Explorer you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (Select All) to see the values:

[image: Much Appreciated]

You can even keep playing like this, but why would you?
In Chrome that didn't work for me - the numbers still invisible.

Comment: Why would you start playing in the first place? That's the real question here.

Comment: @fredley very party pooper

Comment: That's amazing, but what i noticed is that it differs from the other game, instead of one square you get two each time you move, i was playing on chrome, does that happen in firefox too? is the game actually rigged to allow you to suceed more easily than the other one, i mean, i got a much higher score on this than i did on 2048 "the original"

Comment: @Alex The original 2048 also gives you two tiles sometimes. The code for the game mechanics is identical in both games. You just got lucky.

Comment: whats with all the hate for this game? I love this game.

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox anymore :(

Answer (score 10):

If you make it to 4096, the game reuses the 1024 tile. Note that this is a 1024 tile in aesthetics only, and cannot be combined with true 1024 tiles.