# What happens when your score reaches 2048?

Tags: flappy2048

In the new game [Flappy 2048](http://hczhcz.github.io/Flappy-2048/) what happens when your score reaches this magic number, and through what colors does your tile change during its journey?

Comment: @Sterno [Care to revise your statement?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/160556/which-doge-represents-what-number/160558#comment215410_160558)

Comment: When will it ever end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overlay will not show, as i tested (with barriers removed).

The tile's appearance is the same as it is 2048.

Answer (score 4):

Everything is essentially the same as the original [2048](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/). Once you have a 2048 tile, the game will give you the option to continue. It is worth noting, however, that the timer will *not* stop when the overlay is shown, but keyboard input will still be rejected. If you wish to keep playing beyond 2048 points, you had better be quick dismissing the overlay.

As for the colours, they are again the same as 2048, but for half the value. So a tile with value 2 will have the 2048 style for a 4 tile, an 8 tile will have the same as a 16, etc.

Source: <strike>completing the game</strike> digging through the code.