# What would happen if you combine 2 doges in doge 2048?

Tags: doge2048

I'm playing doge2048, and I'm wondering what would happen if you combine 2 '2048' doges?

I ask, because when I change the aspect to 4096 it simply disappears.

I would like to have an answer that's not "you can't" or "it disappears".

Answer (score 1):

According to an answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/162387/80141), you can combine 2 2048 tiles, and it will reuse the 2014 doge icon.